# How to save GeoDjango forms?

Tags: postgis, geodjango

I'm trying to implement creating custom geographic object by GeoDjango. In model I have this field.

```
mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField()
```

Then I create form

```
 from django.contrib.gis import forms as geoforms
 from world.models import Country

 class CountryForm(geoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        widgets = {
            'mpoly': geoforms.OSMWidget(attrs={'map_width': 800, 'map_height': 500}),
        }
```

and rendered it by

```
<head>{{ form.media }}</head>
<body>
   <form>
      {{form}}
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
   </form>
</body>
```

Full page code is [here](https://pastebin.com/Ja82GSj5)

After drawing polygon on map I get error in MapWidget.searializeFeatures function.

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.Y is not a function
at bp (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.20.1/ol.js:459:803)
at Zo.k.Te (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.20.1/ol.js:464:27)
at Zo.k.od (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.20.1/ol.js:431:47)
at MapWidget.serializeFeatures (http://localhost:8000/gstatic/gis/js/OLMapWidget.js:227:69)
at D.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/gstatic/gis/js/OLMapWidget.js:89:22)
at D.b (https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/build/ol.js:41:394)
at Dc.b (https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/build/ol.js:44:213)
at D.k.Be (https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/build/ol.js:47:617)
at D.k.push (https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/build/ol.js:48:41)
at Qt.k.Nd (https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/build/ol.js:634:301)
```

I can't find anything meaningful about this error.

What is the reason for this error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with GeoJSON, or anything spatial. Simply as a redflag,

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.Y is not a function
at bp (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.20.1/ol.js:459:803)
[...]
at Qt.k.Nd (https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/build/ol.js:634:301)
```

That means you're running v4.0.1, and v3.20.1. That seems likely to a cause a problem. There are [major differences](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v4.0.0).

1. I would think you would need to work to remove 3.20.1. See what's including it and nuke that include statement.
2. file a bug if you're not including it to upgrade to v.x You probably don't want two versions of a massive library like openlayers in your site.